# How to put in/out ruby script in database in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I write some simple tests for one site, and I use to do something like that: ruby file -> require selenium-webdriver -> initial webdriver -> go to url -> check some information (title, h1 and etc) -> save the result.

---

Now I want to do the same staff, but use RoR(I am new in RoR). So, every case consist of 3 parts: initial_part ->part_with_instruction -> save_result_in_db. The first and the last parts are always the same, so, I put them in helpers. The second part usually looks like:

```
scenario_log_in(@marker['lng'])
    scenario__menu(@marker['menu_name1'], @marker['check1'], @marker['check2'])
    sleep 5
    is_source(@marker['menu_name1'], @marker['menu_name1'])
    find_and_click_menu(@marker['menu_name1'])
    find_img(@marker['menu_name1'], @marker['menu_pic1'])
```

So, in every case - different code. Can I put ruby code in database? @marker is already save in db. I want to do create structure like that:

```
@my_tests = Test.all 
@my_tests.each do |my_test|
  initial_part
  my_test
  save_result_in_db
end
```

How I can manage this at? It there way to put data in db, and read as ruby-code, not as string?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to store Ruby code in a field? Ruby scripts are text so, yes, they can be stored as text, but they will be treated as a string because that's what text is converted to when retrieved from the database.

Comment: Yes, I want to store Ruby code in a field... Or I want to find alternative solution for my problem - change the second part of test dynamically...